# Unable to click on the 'Sign up with Email' button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I want to click on the "Sign up with email" button. When I click on the 'SIGN UP' link on the https://www.starwars.com/. Could you please help on the same.

[image]

I have written the below code. It doesn't throw any error but doesn't click on the "Sign up with email" button.

```
homePage.click_signUpWithEmailBtn();

//Buttons
    private By signUpWithEmailBtn  = getLocator("a.btn.btn-email.ng-isolate-scope", BY_TYPE.BY_CSSSELECTOR);

public void click_signUpWithEmailBtn(){     
        Assert.assertTrue(this.signUpWithEmailBtn_Presence(), "'Sign up with email' button is absent on the home page.");
        takeScreenshot("Click on 'Sign up with email' button on the home page.");
        click(signUpWithEmailBtn);  
        takeScreenshot("Click on 'Sign up with email' button on the home page.");
    }
```

Comment: Share the code you have tried so far and provide the console error you received.

Answer (score 2):

The Create account is present inside the **iframe**. To click on the **Sign up with email** you need to switch to the corresponding iframe before proceeding with the click.

*Find the below code in Java to switch between the nested frames.*

**Switch to Outter frame**

It does not have any id or name. So switch with web element parameter.

```
WebElement outterFrameElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@allowtransparency='true']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(outterFrameElement);
```

**Switch to Inner frame:**

*Inner iframe ID* = **disneyid-iframe**

```
driver.switchTo().frame("disneyid-iframe");
```

To switch out of frame or to the default content, use the below one.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Note that `disneyid-iframe` located inside another `iframe` (`<iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden;display:block;" src="https://secure.starwars.com/_swdid/www.starwars.com?loc=en-US" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">`), so you should switch to each of them consequently starting from outer `iframe`

Comment: @Andersson Good catch! and modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
driver.switchTo().frame("disneyid-iframe");
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://secure.starwars.com/_swdid/www.starwars.com')")
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe );
driver.findElement("//a[text()='Sign up with email']").click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Note that disneyid-iframe located inside another iframe (`<iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden;display:block;" src="https://secure.starwars.com/_swdid/www.starwars.com?loc=en-US" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">`), so you should switch to each of them consequently starting from outer iframe

Answer (score 0):

As per the url `https://www.starwars.com/` to invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Sign up with email** you need to:

- Induce WebDriverWait for the element with text as **SIGNUP** to be clickable.
- Induce WebDriverWait for the **parent** *iframe to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce WebDriverWait for the **child** *iframe to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce WebDriverWait for the element with text as **Sign up with email** to be clickable.
- You can use the following solution.

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    url = 'https://www.starwars.com/'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='nav-utility']//div[@class='disid-signup log-in-out']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='starwars.com?loc=en-US']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#disneyid-iframe[name='disneyid-iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-email ng-isolate-scope' and contains(@ng-click,'emailSignUp')]"))).click()
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: starwars_create_account]